# KeePassXC suddenly always modal...possible causes?

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, keepassxc

**Background:** KeePassXC 2.6.6 is the latest version from June.  My computer is newer than that, so this is the only version I've ever run on it, installed from `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/phoerious/keepassxc/ubuntu focal main` from the start.  I'm running Linux Mint 20.3 (with MATE 1.26.0).  Everything was working fine until a few days ago.

**Problem:** For some reason, KeePassXC is now always modal:

- Alt-tabbing to another program (or clicking another program's taskbar button) gives the other program the focus (even the keyboard) but leaves KeePassXC on top.  I.e., I'm typing underneath the window I'm looking at.
- Even hitting the start button to bring up the Mint menu causes it to come up underneath KeePassXC.
- This is all true whether KeePassXC is fullscreen or not, and it doesn't matter if I'm in an entry, at the main list, or looking at search results.

**Workaround (not great---impedes normal workflow quite a bit):** Now the only way to get KeePassXC from covering other programs is to minimize it.

**Answers I *think* I've ruled out:**

- Since KeePassXC itself wasn't updated, I'm not sure it's the source of the problem, even though it's the only program exhibiting this behavior.
- One of [its dependencies](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/blob/develop/INSTALL.md#build-dependencies) is Qt 5, but that (well, a bunch of `libqt5*` packages, but none of the other ones listed like `qtbase5`), according to `dpkg.log`, was last updated Jan 7th, quite a bit longer ago than when I believe the problem started happening (~Jan 20th).
- None of the other dependencies have been updated since Jan 7th.
- I haven't touched any of the settings within KeePassXC.
- Full cold boots do not fix the problem.

**Question:** What other system updates or changes could have broken it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I hit Ctrl+Shift+A at some point without realizing it.  I didn't know it at the time, but that's the shortcut for the "View → Always on Top" menu item, which I didn't realize existed, and has no apparent equivalent amongst the "Tools → Settings" list, despite many similar options being there.

Comment: Thanks ! Just happened to me too and my first reflex was to look into KeepassXC Settings.